# temporary queues for msmq

Tags: queue, msmq, temporary

In the JMS world there is this concept called temporary destinations which is very heplful for request/response scenarios. The sender makes request on some destination and  creates a temporary destination (which  exists only as long as the session it is created in is stil there)for receving the responses.
Is there such a thing for msmq?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Its seems to me that this concept ( of sessions ) is strange in a queuing scenario.